# ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView, ListView cannot be cast to TextView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, textview, android-arrayadapter

I created two fragments, one fragment uses listview for displaying items and one fragment uses textview for displaying text when clicking the items of that another fragment. In main activity i use these two fragments one below one. but i have two errors namely

> 1)java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
>   2) java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

MainActivity.java

```
package perception.vicky.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements platformsfragment.ListSelectionListener {

public static String[] titles;
public static String[] details;
private detailsfragment detailsreference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get the string arrays with the titles and details
    titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Titles);
    details = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Quotes);

    // Get a reference to the detailsfragment
    detailsreference = (detailsfragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// Called when the user selects an item in the platformsfragment
@Override
public void onListSelection(int index) {

    if (detailsreference.getShownIndex() != index) {

        // Tell the detailsfragment to show the quote string at position index
        detailsreference.showQuoteAtIndex(index);
    }

}
}
```

platformsfragment.java

```
package perception.vicky.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
* Created by Vicky on 7/23/2015.
*/
public class platformsfragment extends ListFragment {

private ListSelectionListener platformlistener = null;
private View view;

// Callback interface that allows this Fragment to notify the MainActivity when
// user clicks on a List Item
public interface ListSelectionListener {
    void onListSelection(int index);
}

// Called when the user selects an item from the List
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    // Indicates the selected item has been checked
    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);

    // Inform the MainActivity that the item in position pos has been selected
    platformlistener.onListSelection(position);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {

        // Set the ListSelectionListener for communicating with the MainActivity
        platformlistener = (ListSelectionListener) activity;

    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.platformsfragment, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Set the list choice mode to allow only one selection at a time
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    // Set the list adapter for the ListView
    // Discussed in more detail in the user interface classes lesson
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.platformsfragment, android.R.id.list, MainActivity.titles));
}
}
```

detailsfragment.java

```
package perception.vicky.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
* Created by Vicky on 7/23/2015.
*/
public class detailsfragment extends Fragment {

private TextView detailstext=null;
private int DetailsArrayLen;
private int Indx = -1;
private View view;

public detailsfragment() {
}

public int getShownIndex() {
    return Indx;
}

// Show the Quote string at position newIndex
public void showQuoteAtIndex(int newIndex) {
    if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= DetailsArrayLen)
        return;
    Indx = newIndex;
    detailstext.setText(String.valueOf(MainActivity.details[Indx]));
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

// Called to create the content view for this Fragment
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout defined in detailsfragment.xml
    // The last parameter is false because the returned view does not need to be attached to the container ViewGroup
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailsfragment, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.detailsfragment,R.id.textId,MainActivity.details);
    //setListAdapter(adapter);
    detailstext = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textId);
    DetailsArrayLen = MainActivity.details.length;
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="perception.vicky.fragments.platformsfragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/platformsfragment"
    android:id="@+id/platforms"
    android:layout_above="@+id/details"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="perception.vicky.fragments.detailsfragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/detailsfragment"
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

platformsfragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:textSize="32sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

detailsfragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/textId"
    android:layout_height="291dp"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You have to provide resource id of a `TextView` in `ArrayAdapter` to bind its values. You have provided `android.R.id.list`. Replace it with the `TextView` which should be defined in `platformsfragment.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.platformsfragment, android.R.id.list, MainActivity.titles)
```

Try to replace this code with:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.listitem, android.R.id.text1, MainActivity.titles)
```

**listitem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</TextView></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you sir, those two errors are gone, but now i got another two errors: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{perception.vicky.fragments/perception.vicky.fragments.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment,   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment @peter

Comment: got an output sir, i changed android.R.id.text1 to R.id.textview and i used existing return method in onCreateView sir, thank you so much sir, I've been trying this for two days... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You got this line wrong:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.platformsfragment, android.R.id.list, MainActivity.titles)
```

If you consult the documentation, you can see that you are passing wrong values to the constructor. Check this link: [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T[]))

The second parameter is the id of the layout user for the list items, not the layout of the fragment.
The third parameter is the id of a TextView, inside the list item layout, that should be used to present information for each item, not the id of the list you want to populate.

Comment: thank you sir, those two errors are gone, but now i got another two errors: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{perception.vicky.fragments/perception.vicky.fragments.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment,   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: This means that an exception occurred while trying to inflate your platformsfragment. I suggest you debug it's lifecycle methods and track the error.

Comment: got an output sir, i changed android.R.id.text1 to R.id.textview and i used existing return method in onCreateView sir, thank you so much sir, I've been trying this for two days... :-)